# Form Resize Event

Tags: vb.net

I am working on this program - VB. net and there is something I really don't understand it and I am really struggling with it.

The requirements of the program is when it comes to Form Resize Event, I have to do the following:

a.The three buttons are always aligned on the top without any space between. As a group, they are
always horizontally centered on the form.

b. The two labels are always aligned on top, so are the two textboxes.

c. Each label is left aligned with the textbox below it, and the space between a label and the textbox
below it is always 10.

d. When the form is resized, the bottom margin (the space below the buttons), the middle margin
(the space between the textboxes and buttons), and the top margin (the space above the labels)
are the same.

e. The left margin (the space to the left of the input textbox) is the same as the right margin (the
space to the right of the square root textbox). The space between the two textboxes is half of the
left/right margin.

Would anyone be able to explain to me and give me some examples please?

Thank you

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, can't you just use docked panels (nested if need be) to keep everything aligned? As long as you set their z-order correctly you can do it all without writing any code.

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You should add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form and then add the controls to that. You can leave rows or columns empty and use percentages to size them in order to maintain constant proportional spacing. For instance, if you have five rows with controls in the first, third and fifth and set the heights of the second and fourth to 50% then you'll maintain constant proportional spacing between the rows. You just need to use some logic and experimentation.